# Foreach in function

Tags: php

I got a question that hopefully is easy to answer.

In the function below the part "foreach($daten as $row)" is ignored in the second turn. Can somebody tell me, why the function acts that way?

I already tried to delete the "break"... no success.

```
function verweis_show($string,$art,$daten){


$ausgang = preg_split("/\[-\[(.*?)\/(.*?)\/(.*?)\]-\]/", $string,0,PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

$n = 0;

foreach($ausgang as $teil)
{
    $n++;

    if($n == 1)
    {
        $ergebnis .= $teil;

    }
    elseif($n == 2)
    {
        $stat_id = $teil;

    }
    elseif($n == 3)
    {
        $rel_id = $teil;

        if ($art != "old")
        {
            $z = 0;

            // wird im zweiten durchlauf seltsamerweise nicht noch einmal durchlaufen
            foreach($daten as $row) 
            { 
                $z++;

                if ($row['id'] == $stat_id)
                {
                    $rel_id = $z; 
                    break;
                }

            }
        }
    }
    elseif($n == 4)
    {
        $ergebnis .= "<div contenteditable='false' id='text_$stat_id' class='$teil' tabindex='-1'>$rel_id</div>";
        $n = 0;
    }
}

return $ergebnis;
```

}

Comment: Are you sure $daten is an array?

Comment: Thanks for answering. Yes it indeed is.

Comment: Okay. Followup question: Are you sure there is more than one item in $daten? Otherwise, you code looks good.

Comment: Try echo count($daten);

Comment: I think you were right in the first place. Just checked $daten with print_r and got the following output: "PDOStatement Object ( [queryString] => SELECT * FROM tr_inhalt WHERE template_id=28 ORDER BY place ASC )" Seems like you found the problem... I'll check that out! thank you so far :)

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: That went very fast! thank you so much... I looked for the problem 1 hour or so. Thought it was an obvious thing. EDIT: can i give you thumbs up or something?

Comment: You can accept my answer if you like, or upvote it. I'd appreciate the extra reputation :).

Comment: Thank you for that.

Comment: you're welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Foreach requires that it either has an array, or an object that has the [traversable interface](http://php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php) implemented, which PDOStatement probably does not.